# Can you git add new files during the Husky "commit-msg" hook?

Tags: javascript, git, npm, husky, git-husky

I am trying to setup an auto-versioning system where if I `git commit` with the message `PATCH: {message}`, the app's patch version will automatically update (and likewise for a prefix of `MINOR` and `MAJOR` as well). I am using [Husky](https://www.npmjs.com/package/husky) for my `pre-commit` and `pre-push` hook, so I am trying to get this working with a `.husky/commit-msg` hook that looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
. "$(dirname -- "$0")/_/husky.sh"

npm run auto-version $1 && git add --all
```

This works as desired with my `auto-version.js` script automatically reading the commit message and updating `./version.json` accordingly. The only problem is the commit is created with the old `version.json` file and I'm unsure why. I can tell the `git add` is functional because I am left with the updated `version.json` file sitting in the `Staged Changes` section after committing. My `.husky/pre-commit` hook looks like  such and stages updated files prior to committing just fine:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
. "$(dirname -- "$0")/_/husky.sh"

npm run lint && npm run format && git add --all
```

I think this could be related to the timing between when the `commit-msg` hook is fired and when `git` will accept newly staged files, but Husky doesn't provide great docs on how the `commit-msg` hook functions. I also tried setting this up using the `pre-commit` hook instead, but the new commit message does not get saved to `.git/COMMIT_EDITMSG` at this stage (only the old commit message is present).

For some additional context, we are currently just firing `npm version patch --no-git-tag-version` on the `pre-commit` hook and then manually changing the minor and major versions when needed. I wanted to make a more robust and automatic system, which lead to this blocker.

###### auto-version.js

```
const { readFileSync, writeFileSync } = require('fs');

const versionJsonPath = './version.json';
const commitMessagePath = '.git/COMMIT_EDITMSG';

const prefixOptions = ['PATCH', 'MINOR', 'MAJOR'];
const postfixMinLength = 12;

(() => {
    // read commit message
    const rawMessage = readFileSync(commitMessagePath, 'utf-8');
    const message = rawMessage.split(/\r?\n/)[0];
    console.log(`Reading commit message "${message}"...`);

    // check for merge commit
    if (message.startsWith('Merge branch')) {
        process.exit();
    }

    // check for core composition
    const messageParts = message.split(':');
    if (messageParts.length != 2) {
        throwError(`Commit message should take the form "{${prefixOptions.join('|')}}: {message}".`);
    }

    // check for valid prefix
    const messagePrefix = messageParts[0];
    if (!prefixOptions.includes(messagePrefix)) {
        throwError(`Commit message prefix must be one of the following version types: [${prefixOptions.join(', ')}].`);
    }

    // check for valid postfix
    const messagePostfix = messageParts[1];
    if (messagePostfix.trim().length < postfixMinLength) {
        throwError(`Commit message postfix must be at least ${postfixMinLength} characters.`);
    }

    // update app version
    const versionJson = JSON.parse(readFileSync(versionJsonPath, 'utf-8'));
    const oldVersion = versionJson.appVersion;
    const versionParts = oldVersion.split('.').map(v => parseInt(v, 10));

    if (messagePrefix == 'MAJOR') {
        versionParts[0]++;
        versionParts[1] = 0;
        versionParts[2] = 0;
    } else if (messagePrefix == 'MINOR') {
        versionParts[1]++;
        versionParts[2] = 0;
    } else {
        versionParts[2]++;
    }

    const newVersion = versionParts.join('.');
    versionJson.appVersion = newVersion;

    console.log(`Updating app version from ${oldVersion} to ${newVersion}...`);
    writeFileSync(versionJsonPath, JSON.stringify(versionJson));

    process.exit();
})();

function throwError(message) {
    console.error(message);
    process.exit(1);
}
```

###### version.json

```
{
    "appVersion": "0.12.15"
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking at another post ([Git hook commit-msg git add file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35439327/14250695)), it seems that doing `git add` is not possible during/after the `commit-msg` hook stage. Based on one of the answers there, I solved the problem by using a `post-commit` hook to amend the commit to include the updated `version.json` file with `git commit --amend -C HEAD -n version.json`.

###### .husky/post-commit

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
. "$(dirname -- "$0")/_/husky.sh"

npm run auto-version-post-commit
```

The `post-commit` script ensures there is a `version.json` file to add to prevent infinite git hook recursion:

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;

const versionJsonPath = 'version.json';

(() => {
    exec('git diff --name-only', (error, stdout, stderr) => {
        const modifiedFiles = stdout.trim().split(/\r?\n/);

        // check if version.json has been modified by commit-msg hook
        if (modifiedFiles.includes(versionJsonPath)) {
            // amend the last commit to include the updated version.json
            exec(`git commit --amend -C HEAD -n ${versionJsonPath}`);
        }
    });
})();
```