# Get Git commit hash from commit message

Tags: git

Is it possible to get the hash of a commit from a commit message?

I ran the following `git log | grep tap` and got a list of commit messages only, no hashes.

I need to cherry-pick a few of the listed commits, but don't want to manually search for them all to find the commit hashes.

Comment: `git log --grep=tap` might be more what you need

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yep you can.

You have minor mistake in your command:
The correct command is to use the `--grep` as flag to the log and not as a unix command after the pipe `|`

```
git log --grep=".. any text you need to find ..."
```

[image]

---

> ***`git log --grep=<pattern>`***
>
> Limit the commits output to ones with log message that **matches the specified pattern** (regular expression).
>
> With more than one `--grep=<pattern>`, commits whose message matches any of the given patterns are chosen (but see `--all-match`).
>
> When `--show-notes` is in effect, the message from the notes is matched as if it were part of the log message.

Comment: very good answer! I dont have the problem but now I am smarter.

Comment: Thank you, Here are some other great answers which you can learn from:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34519665/how-to-move-head-checkout-revert-reflog-reset/34519716#34519716

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35400416/what-are-some-more-forceful-ways-than-a-gitignore-to-keep-force-files-out-of/35400472#35400472