# .gitignored files still shown in RStudio

Tags: r, git, rstudio

I added the folder `.Rproj.user` to `.gitignore`. However, some files contained in it still show up (see screenshot). Any ideas what can I do about it?

[image]

**Update**

No changes after adding `.Rproj.user/**`

[image]

Answer (score 41, accepted):

First of all your files are already committed so you have to remove it from the repo:

```sh
# Once you add files to git, it will keep tracking them,  
# so we have to delete them and commit your deletion
git rm -r --cached .Rproj.user/**

# Commit the deleted files
git commit -m "Removed files...."

# now add it to the `.gitignore` and the files will be ignored
echo '.Rproj.user/**' > .gitignore
```

You need to mark it as folder.
In order to do so add the 2 `**` as described above

[image]

## ***`P.S.`***

Here is a cool hook which will block that kind of files to be added when you try to push them to the server.

[What are some more forceful ways than a .gitignore to keep (force) files out of a repo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35400416/what-are-some-more-forceful-ways-than-a-gitignore-to-keep-force-files-out-of/35400472#35400472)

Comment: I see why, its already in your repo. first you have to remove it:

Comment: `git rm --cached .Rproj.user/**` then commit the changes and git ignore will catch from this point

Comment: Updated the answer accordinaly

Comment: I needed to add `-r`, i.e. `git rm -r --cached .Rproj.user/**` and then it worked like a charm. Thanks! :)

Comment: Awesome! Thank you! This has bugged me for a long time.