# .gitignore is not ignoring large directories

Tags: c++, git, qt, boost

I have massive folders in my git repository, and in order to publish it, I need to reduce the size of the repository, so I'm using a .gitignore file.

In my .gitignore file I ignore two folders.  One folder contains the boost c++ library, and the other contains the C++ Qt library.

Both are massive.  However, when I specify in my .gitignore file to exclude these folders and their contents, it actually adds to the amount of objects to be pushed.

Here is my `.gitignore`

```
boost_1_60_0/
Qt/
ERRORLOG.rtf
CHANGELOG.rtf
```

Any ideas on what may be causing this?

Comment: You can add a .gitignore file per directory in your file system but you can also do a {directory name}/**/*  to exclude everything within that folder.

Comment: the {directory name}/**/* does not seem to be working.

Comment: Am I supposed to enclose the directory name in brackets, or is that your way of delimiting the folder name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add `xxx/**` or it will be tracked as files and not folders.

Folders pattern is `/**`.

If you already added the file to your staging area you have to remove it using the `git rm --cached <pattern>`.

Here is a very similar questions with the same issue more or less:

[.gitignored files still shown in RStudio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36185456/gitignored-files-still-shown-in-rstudio/36185597#36185597)