# change .gitignore after some commits/push

Tags: git, gitignore, socialengine

I have created a repository in my github account with a socialengine php project without `.gitignore` file.

Then I clone the repository localyl and I create a .gitignore file and i write some lines of paths to ignore files and folders.
As an example

```
temporary/log
temporary/session
temporary/package
```

There is a file `auth.php` in `install/config/auth.php` path and I write also in my `.gitignore` file the path of it to ignore it as follows

```
install/config
```

During the installation I see that the subfolders of temporary folder are ignored.

The think is that when I am in the installation step where some authentication lines of code should be written in auth.php file, the file auth.php looks unstaged when I type `git status`.
I can not figure out why this happens although I have included the path (install/config) in .gitignore file.

I have tried also `install/config/`, `install/config/*` but nothing.

If I use `git rm --cached install/config/auth.php` then the file will be deleted remotely something that must not happen because this file is needed to exist for socialengine installation and for future installation.

There is any idea what I can do for this situation ?

Comment: Do you want to make local changes to a commited file but you need git to ignore local changes?

Comment: exactly should be ignored this local change in auth.php file because it has to do with the local installation. File auth.php is not needed to be commited/pushed because other developers on their PCs will have also their local auth.php

Answer (score 2):

## Don't do that!

What you have done here is to assign the responsibility of maintaining the *local* `auth.php` file to the *source system that uses it*.

Consider the following line of thought.  Imagine you're the *user* of the system, which you get from the vendor.  Every quarter, the vendor ships you a new system.  But you reconfigure whenever you shuffle your servers around, which is every month, or sometimes more or less frequently based on load.

How often should you, as the *user*, commit your own personal configuration?  Well, every time it changes, if you are source-controlling it at all.  That's monthly, more or less.

Every *three* months, the vendor ships you the latest version of the system ... with a new configuration he foists upon you, even though that's not *your* configuration.  That's just *wrong*.  Not only did you not want a new configuration from *him*, *your* schedule of configuration changes is not *his* schedule.

The solution is: **as the vendor, don't do that.**  Don't put the *local* configuration into the *source* at all.  Your users will have their own local configuration, which they store separately from *your* code, maybe even in a completely separate repository.

#### "But my users are stupid!  I must foist a configuration upon them!"

Well, that's fine; many are.  Go ahead and include an *initial* configuration, or a *default* configuration.  If your users have not set up *their own* configuration, use that—maybe even copy it into place *as* the local configuration.  But then, after that, *don't touch their local configuration.*<sup>1</sup>  Update the initial and/or default configurations, sure.  But don't touch the user's *local* configuration.

---

<sup>1</sup>Except, perhaps, for migrations: if the user is upgrading from version 1.7 to version 2.1, you can *migrate* their local configuration to add new features.  Depending on your configuration file format, you may also need to support *reverse* migration, should they wish to downgrade from 2.1 back to 1.7.

Comment: not understand exactly what you explain. the auth.php file has one line of code with an md5 string and is generated during installation. This happens and must happens for each installation seperately.

Comment: OK, so, it's not really a *configuration*, but it's still something you *generate once*. You do not store it as part of the source! On Unix-like systems, such files should normally be stored in `/var/db` somewhere, e.g., `/var/db/foo/md5` for program `foo`. (In Windows, probably the right place is the Windows registry, though I don't do Windows.)

Comment: its a file auth.php that uses socialengine for the installation. But still have a question why gitignore ignores temporary subfolders and not install/config/auh.php file. Strange for me

Comment: If a file is in the index, it is tracked, and nothing in any ignore file will change that. If a file is *not* in the index, it is untracked. If the file is in a commit, checking out that commit puts it into the index, and hence into the work-tree. If the file is *not* in a commit, but *is* currently in the index, checking out that commit *removes* the file from the index, and hence also from the work-tree. An entry in `.gitignore` does not mean "ignore the file", it means "do not complain about the file's untracked-ness when untracked, and do not auto-add the file with a mass add operation."

Comment: yeah thanks, as ena example the auto-generated files like logs are untracked because there is in gitignore a rule to ignore them but the auth.php is already tracked so a rule on it make no sense.

Comment: @apo Did you manage to ignore your already pushed file that you want to ignore?

Comment: @MohammedNAIMI remove it push and then add in gitignore a line. If the file exists again then its gonna be ignored.

Answer (score 1):

#### Local ignore

You need to use the `assume-unchanged` flag
https://git-scm.com/docs/git-update-index

```
# To temporarily ignore changes in a certain file, run:
git update-index --assume-unchanged <file>

# When you want to track changes again:
git update-index --no-assume-unchanged <file>
```

#### Server side ignore

Read this full answer with a full code to do it on the server side:
[What are some more forceful ways than a .gitignore to keep (force) files out of a repo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35400416/what-are-some-more-forceful-ways-than-a-gitignore-to-keep-force-files-out-of/35400472#35400472)

---

> #### --[no-]assume-unchanged
>
> When this flag is specified, the object names recorded for the paths are not updated.
>
> Instead, this option sets/unsets the "assume unchanged" bit for the paths.
>
> When the `assume unchanged` bit is on, the user promises not to change the file and allows Git to assume that the working tree file matches what is recorded in the index. If you want to change the working tree file, you need to unset the bit to tell Git. This is sometimes helpful when working with a big project on a filesystem that has very slow lstat(2) system call (e.g. cifs).
>
> Git will fail (gracefully) in case it needs to modify this file in the index e.g. when merging in a commit; thus, in case the assumed-untracked file is changed upstream, you will need to handle the situation manually.

[image]

Comment: For my understanding this is a local solution. Each developer can use this to ignore the auth.php file. My thought is why git can not ignore it directly from .gitignore. May windows be a part of the problem...

Comment: You can do it with git hook on the server side to "ignore" the file when its commited.

Answer (score 0):

I pushed .idea folder by mistake, that contains some IDE settings, then, tracking all changes made to .idea bothered me. so I followed these steps

- Add all the files, individually or in a folder, that you want to remove from the repo but keep locally to .gitignore.
- Execute git rm --cached put/here/your/file.ext for each file or git
  rm --cached folder/* if they are in a folder. (It is /* because you
  need to escape the *)
- Commit your changes.
- Push to remote.

Then, I reverted the folder that I am no longer willing to track using git. here is a helpfull thread in [Link](https://superuser.com/questions/1397199/how-to-ignore-a-tracked-file-in-git-without-deleting-it)