# Is there a way to allow access to specific files via git from bitbucket/any other provider to maintain privacy of code files from all?

Tags: git, version-control, bitbucket

I have repo of a sdk and the team spread across. We need to keep the code private and secure from getting corrupted.

So can we have an option to enable single/specific file access to the bitbucket users via git repo setup?

Comment: Not file specific no. You can lock branches and only merge with an approved pull-request.

Comment: You CAN !!!!! using git hooks if you need specific files and for full repo, access use the bitucket configuration (repository permissions)

Comment: Take a look here: (add the required user as well to "block" access https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35400416/what-are-some-more-forceful-ways-than-a-gitignore-to-keep-force-files-out-of/35400472#35400472

Answer (score 1):

I cant post images on comments so if this is what you are looking for I will update the answer with the full explanation on how and what to do.

You can limit and restrict access to your repo & ranches from the settings screen:

#### Restrict access to repository/ranches

[image]

---

#### Restrict changes to specific files (or allow it to certain users)

### ***[`pre-receive hook`](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks#pre-receive-KpTEIPiaik)***

```bash
#!/bin/sh

# Check to see if this is the first commit in the repository or not
if git rev-parse --verify HEAD >/dev/null 2>&1
then
    # We compare our changes against the previous commit
    against=HEAD^
else
    # Initial commit: diff against an empty tree object
    against=4b825dc642cb6eb9a060e54bf8d69288fbee4904
fi

# Redirect output to screen.
exec 1>&2

# Check to see if we have updated the given file
if [ $(git diff-tree -r --name-only $against | grep <ANY FILE YOU WANT TO FILTER OUT HERE> ) ];
then

# -> ADD YOUR CODE TO CHECK CERTAIN USER 
# -> (grab it from the commit for example) 

    # Output colors
    red='\033[0;31m';
    green='\033[0;32m';
    yellow='\033[0;33m';
    default='\033[0;m';

    # personal touch :-)
    echo "${red}"
    echo "                                         "
    echo "                   |ZZzzz                "
    echo "                   |                     "
    echo "                   |                     "
    echo "      |ZZzzz      /^\            |ZZzzz  "
    echo "      |          |~~~|           |       "
    echo "      |        |-     -|        / \      "
    echo "     /^\       |[]+    |       |^^^|     "
    echo "  |^^^^^^^|    |    +[]|       |   |     "
    echo "  |    +[]|/\/\/\/\^/\/\/\/\/|^^^^^^^|   "
    echo "  |+[]+   |~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~|    +[]|   "
    echo "  |       |  []   /^\   []   |+[]+   |   "
    echo "  |   +[]+|  []  || ||  []   |   +[]+|   "
    echo "  |[]+    |      || ||       |[]+    |   "
    echo "  |_______|------------------|_______|   "
    echo "                                         "
    echo "                                         "
    echo "${red} You are not allowed to commit this file    "
    echo "                                         "
    echo "${default}"
fi;

# set the exit code to 0 or 1 based upon your needs
# 0 = good to push
# 1 = exit without pushing.
exit 0;
```

---

Comment: Thanks @CodeWizard I will try this now

Comment: I am not able to find tht specific UI that you have mentioned at the top.

Comment: are u admin? its only visible to admins

Comment: Yes I am the admin and owner of all repos

Comment: This comment shows how to do things in Bitbucket Server, the self-hosted version. Are you trying to do this in Bitbucket Cloud?

Comment: No I am hosting on bitbucket.org

Comment: Is it Possible in anything other than git such as svn/mercurial

Comment: @CodeWizard Will this work to restrict users to folders in a branch as well?

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not.

For bitbucket git repo, there is **no way** to specify access permission for files for now.

There are three kinds of premissions you can set on bitbucket repo: Admin, Write and Read.
Even for the users who have only read permission, they can access to all the files of the repo.

More details, you can refer the document [Using repository permissions](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/using-repository-permissions-776639771.html), and the post [Can i set files & folders permissions in Bitbucket](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/Can-i-set-files-folders-permissions-in-Bitbucket/qaq-p/78962).

BTW: if you want to suggest the feature (enable to set permission for files/folders) to bitbucket, you can feedback by creating a new issue [here](https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issues?status=new&status=open&component=Pipelines&_ga=2.260069837.1717690962.1525672184-1070372784.1523348894).