# prevent merge PR in bitbucket

Tags: git, merge, bitbucket, webhooks

I want to prevent from bitbucket to merge PR if there are not enough approvers.
I know that this can be done with the premium user but I don't have one so I am trying to find a workaround.

So I was looking into hooks that might do the trick.
However, as fa r as I understand githooks in my repo won't do the trick because they are client hooks. Am I right about it?

Also, I don't have access to the bitbucket server to add their server-side hooks.

can it be done with some webhook using a Jenkins job?
Any helpful reference, tip or other solution are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned you **will need** one of the following:

### Admin user

Admin user will allow you to set up the required approvers
[image]

### Access to the file system

> Also, I don't have access to the bitbucket server to add their server-side hooks.

Once you have access to the filesystem you can add your hooks.

### Git hooks

Once more you are right, local git hooks runs on the client-side.

Here is a sample for server-side hook which you will need to use if you was able to 
[pre-receive hook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35400416/what-are-some-more-forceful-ways-than-a-gitignore-to-keep-force-files-out-of/35400472#35400472)

---

Trying to manage the PR form Jenkins **might work** but its a wrong approach since anyone with the right access can merge the PR form within the bitbucket (Web, source tree, cli etc).

Here is one way to do it with Jenkins:
https://mohamicorp.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/DOC/pages/209059847/Triggering+Jenkins+on+new+Pull+Requests

Comment: thanks for the response.
so basically the correct way is through the file system(or the premium user) but because I don't have any of those I can't enforce a merge check

Comment: Exactly. you need admin user for any of those changes